# Javascript + Angular + Prototype clear object properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a bit confused, I would like to have a function that clears all the properties of an object which is available to all the instances of an object.  So, I have added a  prototype clear() function.  This is the following code:

```
(function () {

Supplier.$inject = [];

angular.module('webclient').factory('Supplier', Supplier);

function Supplier() {

    Supplier.prototype = {
        clear: function () {
            for (var key in this) {
                //skip loop if the property is from prototype
                if (this.hasOwnProperty(key))
                    continue;


                console.log("key:" + key);
                this[key] = undefined;
            }
        },
    }

    return Supplier;
};
})();
```

So, I would like to be able to clear all the properties of the current supplier object.  So, if the supplier object had the following properties:

SupplierID:21,
Email:None

I would like to set the properties to undefined.  I would use the class as following:

var supplier = new Supplier();

supplier.SupplierID = 21;
supplier.Email = "None";

And to set each property to undefined I would

supplier.clear();

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: ([plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vXOKbNgYdp9X2GYD0Fal?p=preview))

```
function Supplier() {
    var supplier = function() {};
    supplier.prototype.clear = function() {
      for (var key in this) {
          if (!this.hasOwnProperty(key))
              continue;
          delete this[key];
      }
    };
    return supplier;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hasOwnProperty return true if key is not in the prototype also prototype should be set outside of constructor, so your code should look like this:

```
function Supplier() { }

Supplier.prototype = {
    clear: function () {
        for (var key in this) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                console.log("key:" + key);
                this[key] = undefined;
            }
        }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't set properties to `undefined`, just `delete()` them:

```
delete this[key];
```

And @jcubic is right, `hasOwnProperty` returns true if key is **not** in the prototype...